# Handheld call Web Service or Stored Procedure look like has been called twice?

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services, stored-procedures, handheld

I have implemented the system that has a lot of frequency transaction and has some problem.
The environment are :

- windows mobile 6.1 c#
- web service on windows 2008
- database sql
- server 2008 r2

by the way, Windows mobile will call web service and web service call stored procedure.
The Problem is about a stored proceduce has command insert line to table such as

```
insert into table(column1,column2) values (value1,value2)
```

and this stored procedure has been called when every user scan barcode.

I monitored the data on the table and I found regular data, but sometimes it looks like the transaction has been called twice on once scan a barcode.

I found it always occur when the transaction frequency is high

For example :

```
row_id  item_barcode  qty  uom  date_trans               maker

1    xxxxxxxxxxxx     2     unit   05/01/2013 10:55:20:527      Smith   ====>**
2    aaaaaaaaaaaa     1     unit   05/01/2013 10:55:20:529      Adam
3    bbbbbbbbbbbb     3     unit   05/01/2013 10:55:20:529      Andy
4    cccccccccccc     7     unit   05/01/2013 10:55:20:532      Michael
5    xxxxxxxxxxxx     2     unit   05/01/2013 10:55:20:535      Smith   ====>**
6    dddddddddddd     9     unit   05/01/2013 10:55:20:540      Jack
7    eeeeeeeeeeee     3     unit   05/01/2013 10:55:20:541      Lauren
```

** Please focus on row_id 1 and 5
It seems to come from the scanned barcode.

I puzzled on it about stored procedure or web service has been called twice on high frequency transaction.

Could someone help me I don't know what's happened

Thank you very much
Wanlop S.

ps. Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

I guess the web service is called twice from client app.